# intent.data is null when launching activity from app link

Tags: android, null, intentfilter, applinks

I looked at related SO but they didn't seem to resolve this issue.

The app supports app linking and website has .well-known/assetlinks.json.

When clicking app link in email, say https://staging.xyz.com/v3/info/7vwD2yjW, the

- main activity should appear
- onCreate() should get URI data from intent.data
- main activity should update itself based on URI data

Launching app from a cold start with a valid app link, the intent.data is always null. However if app had been running or in background, URI intent.data is not null in onNewIntent() and works fine.

Not sure what I am missing. It's running on a Galaxy J3 Prime, Android 7.0. Here is the config. Any ideas how to get intent.data URI from cold start?

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <tools:validation testUrl="https://staging.xyz.com/v3/info/7vwD2yjW" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="xyz.com"
                android:pathPattern="/.*/share" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="xyz.com"
                android:pathPattern="/.*/info/.*" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="*.xyz.com"
                android:pathPattern="/.*/share" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="*.xyz.com"
                android:pathPattern="/.*/info/.*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569433/getting-null-value-from-intent-in-deep-link) . You should override onNewIntent and then handle data from it.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // do stuff with intent
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this works as-is. There was an exception elsewhere causing launch activity to skip updating from URI data. Posting resolution in case it may be useful to anyone else.

To track down I attached debugger to device process during cold start from app link in Android Studio like so:

```
adb shell am set-debug-app -w --persistent com.xyz.appname
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://staging.xyz.com/v3/info/7vwD2yjW" com.xyz.appname
```

Then Run -> Debug -> select debug config with link

An API call is made, and displays a PopupWindow with busy indicator in the launch activity. The popup was throwing exception:

```
BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

To get popup working, in onCreate() popup is displayed after activity startup cycle completes

```
activityRootView.post {
  handleAppLinkIntent(intent) // show busy popup and do stuff with intent.data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to `android:launchMode="singleTask"`